# Flutter app crashes on Android device when I try to launch a new meeting using Jitsi Meet

Tags: android, flutter, dart, jitsi-meet

I have built a Flutter app which lets a user create or join a meeting. I have used Jitsi Meet plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet

I have added a proguard-rules.pro file in android/app folder of my project and added the following code to that file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/master/jitsi_meet/example/android/app/proguard-rules.pro

Here's the buildTypes section of my app/build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           minifyEnabled true
           useProguard true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
```

However, when a user tries to create a new meeting, the app simply crashes.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`useProguard true` property is the one causing the problem. Remove it and leave other properties.

```
buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       minifyEnabled true
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
```

}

Comment: The issue was with a line I included in the build.gradle file in jitsimeet. I was ignoring react native. Once I removed that, things worked.

Comment: @AyanDasgupta what is the android version you are testing?
I'm having this issue only in Android 12.

Comment: @NifalNizar had issues with Android 12 as well (API 31). Did this workaround: 

`<service
            android:name="org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>`

put this inside application tag of AndroidManifest.xml